# Best Table Structure Design for Synchronization or Replication

Tags: azure

Dears,

I have choose the following table structure to be common for all tables in my application :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[equipm](
[id2] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
......
......

 CONSTRAINT [PK22_equipm] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (
[id2] ASC)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

explanation:
**GUID** will be Primary Key not Clustered. Also I will use newsequentialid()
**bigint** will be Unique and clustered Index, and will be used for all relations with other tables.

Question 1: Does this structure is the optimal ? 
Question 2: Shall I use GUID for Primary Key and Relations to other tables since I will use Synchronization or may Replications in future ? if Yes, What are the consequences that I should keep in mind ?

**Extra Information** 
The above design will be used in application which support multi user signing from different geographical locations, also I will use SQL Azure for Sync Databases between Main Office of a company and Branches.

I hope my post is clear
Thanks

Comment: why not using just bigint for that?

Comment: bigint and int are not supported in sql azure also they are susceptible to conflict.